# How to write handler of treeview in controller of extjs4

Tags: controller, extjs4, treeview, handler

i am working in extjs4. i have treeview with checkbox as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.tree1', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
title: 'Simple Tree',
id:'tree1',
alias : 'widget.tree1',
store:'qb.qbquestionStore',
displayField: 'text',
rootVisible : true,
multiSelect : true,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: {
            text: 'Get checked nodes',
            handler: function(){
                var tree = this.up('panel');
                var records = tree.getView().getChecked(),
                    names = [];

                Ext.Array.each(records, function(rec){
                    names.push(rec.get('text'));
                });

                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'Selected Nodes',
                    msg: names.join('<br />'),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                });
            }}}]});
```

So i am getting checked treenodes in this handler function. I want to get those checked nodes in controller of extjs4. so how to write this handler function in controller of extjs4? Or how to get these checked nodes on click of submit button in controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller get a reference to your tree view using refs
This will allow you to access your tree view in the event handler like

`this.getTreeView()`

You can define event handler for button in controller's init function

Try this, if you get stuck post your code and we will help you

**UPDATE:**

Also, you will need to define a xtype on your view
`xtype: 'tree1'`

In your ref, try this:

`refs: [{
         ref: 'treeView',
         selector: 'tree1'
     }],`

Now, you should be able to access `this.getTreeView()` in your controller methods. Let us know how you go.

Comment: Thanx for reply... I had tried as you told. In refs i had written as-    "{ref:'treeview',
selector:'tree1'}"...And inside function if i write console.log(this.getTreeview) is giving me error as undefined. So how to write handler in controller. Please can someone help me

Comment: No problem.I have updated the answer above to include some more info about refs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the component event in the controller init function and call the callback function from there. Please refer below sample.

in view part

```
 this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            }]
```

in controller part

```
init: function() {
        this.control({
           'useredit button[action=save]': {
                click: this.updateUser
            }
        });
    }
 ...
    updateUser: function(button) {
       // write your stuff here.   
    }
```

If you found any difficulties, please refer below sencha guides with example.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/application_architecture

Thanks.